# How to plot two BVPs in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, graphics, mathematical-optimization

I have two BVPs as: $x^{\prime\prime}(t)+tx(t)-t^{3}-2=0$ and  $x^{\prime\prime}(t)+x^{2}(t)-t^{4}-2=0$ and their BCs are $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=1$. Now the function $x(t)=t^{2}$ is their common solution. I want to plot both the above BVPs and wana see in a graph that $x(t)=t^{2}$ is their common solution. I tried Plot common but can not achieve the aim.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code that you have try.

Comment: The initial condition x[0]==1 does not agree with x[t]=t^2

Comment: Dear @Danial I have modified the question

Comment: `eq1 = x''[t] + t x[t] - t^4 - 2 == 0`  t^2 is no solution to the first equation. `eq1 /. x -> (#^2 &)`  yields `t^3 - t^4 == 0`

Comment: Solving with DSolve/NDSolve and Plotting are covered in the docs for them. Without code to show what’s difficult I’d say this is covered by the docs.

Comment: Dear @Michael I have correct eq1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = x''[t] + t*x[t] - t^3 == 0;
eq2 = x''[t] + x[t]^2 - t^4 - 2 == 0;
bc = {x[0] == 0, x[1] == 1};

sol1 = DSolve[{eq1, bc}, x, t][[1]];

sol1N = NDSolve[{eq1, bc}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]];

sol2 = NDSolve[{eq2, bc}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]];
```

Testing whether `x[t] == t^2` is a solution to the equations

```
eq1 /. x -> (#^2 &)

(* False *)

eq2 /. x -> (#^2 &)

(* True *)

Plot[{x[t] /. sol1, x[t] /. sol1N, x[t] /. sol2, t^2},
 {t, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{
    "eq1: DSolve", "eq1: NDSolve",
    "eq2: NDSolve", t^2},
   {.3, .75}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For revised `eq1`

```
eq1r = x''[t] + t*x[t] - t^3 - 2 == 0;

sol1r = DSolve[{eq1r, bc}, x, t][[1]];

sol1Nr = NDSolve[{eq1r, bc}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Testing whether `x[t] == t^2` is a solution to the revised equation

```
eq1r /. x -> (#^2 &)

(* True *)

Plot[{x[t] /. sol1r, x[t] /. sol1Nr, t^2},
 {t, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed, {Red, Dotted, Thick}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{
    "eq1r: DSolve", "eq1r: NDSolve",
    t^2},
   {.3, .75}]]
```

[image]